# Aligning Header and Search Icon with Body

Tags: html, css

I'm having a few alignment issues with Tumblr.

I'm trying to align a header and search icon.

The site is [here.](http://wearethejamaicanbobsledteam.tumblr.com/)

Below is a mockup I want to achieve:

[image]

If you look at my site you'll see the header and search bar aren't aligned as per my image above.

I've tried different margins etc but to no avail.

Oh, I want it to respond to the browser so it's always aligned.

Comment: @Micheal dear you can easily achieve the desired layout. Just tell me that do you want that Follow an Join tumblr buttons or not?

Comment: @HappySingh No I dont want them.

Comment: @Micheal see my answer and let me know if any issues.

Comment: Now let me know if any issues are still present?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Find the below css rules and paste the css rules there

css: http://wearethejamaicanbobsledteam.tumblr.com/   line: 555

```
 iframe#tumblr_controls {
        position: fixed !important;
        right: -310px !important; // it will move the button to -310px towards right.
        top: 9px !important;
        width: 160px;
        z-index: 5000 !important;
    }
```

To align search box:

css: http://wearethejamaicanbobsledteam.tumblr.com/ line: 150

```
#search {
    border-left: 0 solid #DDDDDD;
    border-right: 0 solid #DDDDDD;
    padding: 20px 15px 6px;
    position: absolute;
    right: 32px; // change the value here
    top: 0;
}
```

To make the Lens icon to from left to right in search box

css: http://wearethejamaicanbobsledteam.tumblr.com/ line: 161

```
#search input[type="text"] {
    background: url("http://static.tumblr.com/twte3d7/V9ym4qy8v/search-white.png") no-repeat scroll 95% 6px #FCFCFC;
    border: 1px solid #DDDDDD;
    border-radius: 0 0 0 0;
    box-shadow: 0 1px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15) inset;
    color: #212121;
    font: 12px 'Karla';
    padding: 6px 15px 7px 35px; **// Update the below rules here**
    transition: all 0.7s ease 0s;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Update the css in above css rules

```
padding: 6px 35px 7px 15px;
```

Comment: my only issue now is that the type overlays the search icon. Is there anyway to prevent it doing that?

Comment: yes it is very easy wait a min let me update it in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

#### CSS Fix

```css
#search {right: 15px;}
```

It is in `Line 150` of your main home page.